# Cant use memcpy to populate Struct

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I am trying to write a program to mimic some assembly code(don't ask me why lol), and it should look something like this.

It should use int value in order to populate the memory of the structure that consists of long values.

When I debug the program, in the first iteration `sizeof(int)*a = 0` and everything is good.

But in the second iteration, `a=1` and `sizeof(int)*1=4`, but `&ss+sizeof(int)*a` is not equal to `&ss+4` but rather to `&ss+0xA0`... Then for `a = 2`, `&ss+0x140`. It is constantly multiplying by 40 (decimal system).

hex `0xA0` = `4*40` decimal. hex `0x140` = `8*40` decimal...

How to make this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    long a[5];
} StructType1;

StructType1 foo()
{
    StructType1 ss;
    int bb = 7;
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 10)
    {
        memcpy(&ss + sizeof(int) * a, &bb, 4);
        a++;
    }

    return ss;
}

int main()
{
    StructType1 s = foo();
    printf("%ld\n", s.a[0]);
}
```

Comment: What if `int` isn't half the size of `long`?

Comment: A pointer always increases in increments of the the size of the data type pointed at.

Comment: 1. I am pretty sure long=8B(QWORD) and int=4B(DWORD), at least by System V ABI reference.
2.  Does that mean when I increase &ss by 1, it will increase by 1*sizeof(type_it_points_to)?

Comment: @LukaSavic if you want a fixed size type, you should use a fixed size type. Long, int, etc are subject to change.

Comment: @LukaSavic Yes, when you increase `&ss` by 1, the address increases by the size of the structure.

Comment: @user3386109 that totally makes sense man. Never thought of that, sizeof(struct) is 5*sizeof(long) and exactly 40B. wow...

Comment: You could probably cast the pointer to char* and get result you are expecting.  (however strange it would be)

Comment: @Taekahn could you explain a bit how are they subject to change? int cant store more that 4B in any case? Of course depends on the architecture, but in this case

Comment: Sounds like you've done your due dilligence and made sure on your target the sizing makes sence. For those that follow, C and C++ only specify the minimum size of integer types and that they cannot be larger than the next type up. `sizeof(int)` can be anywhere from 2 to `sizeof(long)` inclusive. Some folk, Cray for example, have in the past defined them all to be the same size.

Comment: You don't really need the `memcpy`. The following will work. `long bb = 7 + (7 << 32); for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ss.a[i] = bb;`

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for the suggestion, I already tried that, and it was fine, but the point of the exercise was to turn assembly to .c, and it was clearly working with DWORD and putting 10 DWORDS from the starting location. When looking at my assembly code for the .c code above, they are very similar, so I am pretty sure I am nearly there. I am pretty sure I should use int, and memcpy, but i don't see a clear way to do it.
If I use char* and calloc some memory, then I have a problem of returning char* and I must return StructType1.

Comment: If you insist, then using a `char *` allows you to do the address calculations yourself: `char *ptr = &ss;` and `memcpy(ptr + sizeof(int) * a, &bb, sizeof(int));`

Comment: @user3386109 thanks a lot!! should've came to my mind to do it that way.. thanks for the help, learned several things in this discussion :)

Comment: Note: Any object can safely be viewed as an array of characters, what's happening with `char *ptr = &ss;`, but the reverse is not true. You can't be certain that `StructType1 * ssp = (StructType1 *)a_char_array;` is properly aligned in memory or what-not and won't explode in your face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by *user3386109*, the type of `&ss` is *pointer to a `StructType1` object*, thus adding an integer `n` to it computes the address of the `n`-th next object in an array of such objects, multiplying `n` by the size of the object to the get the byte address.

For you purpose, you should cast `&ss` as a pointer to a character type.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    long a[5];
} StructType1;

StructType1 foo(void) {
    StructType1 ss;
    int bb = 7;
    int a = 0;
    int n = sizeof ss / sizeof(int);
    while (a < n) {
        memcpy((char *)&ss + sizeof(int) * a, &bb, sizeof(int));
        a++;
    }
    return ss;
}

int main() {
    StructType1 s = foo();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%ld%c", s.a[i], "    \n"[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```